# What's the quickest way to cut the first 20 bytes out of a byte string in Python?

Tags: python, tcp, pack, unpack

I'm working with a TCP protocol passing a packet from a sender to a receiver. I need to be able to split the header from the content, which populate my "packet."

My header is packed like so

```
tcp_header = pack('!HHLLBBH', tcp_source, tcp_dest, tcp_seq, tcp_ack_seq, tcp_offset_res, tcp_flags,
                          tcp_window) + pack('H', tcp_check) + pack('!H', tcp_urg_ptr)
```

Then my packet is constructed like this

```
packet = tcp_header + user_data
```

I unpack it like this

```
(tcp_source, tcp_dest, tcp_seq, tcp_ack_seq, tcp_offset_res, tcp_flags,\
             tcp_window, tcp_check, tcp_urg_ptr) = unpack('!HHLLBBHHH', sent_packet)
```

But it only works if I send the header alone. How can I split the content from the header before unpacking?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The function you are looking for `struct.unpack_from`,

```
struct.unpack_from('!HHLLBBHHH', sent_packet)
```

Comment: Thanks!. That combined with struct.calcsize put me on the right track.